# Disable specific days

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I am looking for a way to disable specific days in the SharePoint calendar based on an event.  Basically, when we enter an event titled "No new training," it will disable adding any other events for the day.  I think it will have to be java script, but I'm not sure where to start with this, and I don't do much coding in Java.  Any help or advice where to look for the information would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a pattern to the "no new training" days?

Comment: No, there are some days on the schedule that we would like to block off.  We just want a way to keep people from adding new training events if the day gets to full, or we cannot support any more training due to manning or equipment limitations.